# Does the ordering of index arguments matter when initializing memory with readmemb

Tags: verilog

So in order to load memory into a "file" on the FPGA I am using the procedure outlined [here](https://timetoexplore.net/blog/initialize-memory-in-verilog).

The rough formula is this

```
reg [7:0] ex2_memory [0:15];
$readmemh("ex2.mem", ex2_memory);
```

Which is strange to me because a lot of guides suggest it should be slightly different. For example this was in one of my guides

```
Sometimes it can be useful to have structures with more than one dimension – for example, we might want to hold 16 8-bit values. Verilog allows you to define multiple sets of indexes for a variable:
      reg [7:0] string [15:0];
```

Notice how there it is [n:0] instead of [0:n] in the readmemb example. So what is the difference between these two ways of defining this multidimensional bus?

Answer (score 0):

For Verilog, the unpacked dimension order does not matter. `$readmemh/b` always maps the starting address to the lower index, and you can only access one memory element at a time. There is a rare exception for C code when using the Verilog Programming Interface (VPI), but did I say that was rare?

In SystemVerilog it matters more because you can access unpacked arrays as a whole or use part selects similar to the way Verilog allows part selects of packed vector dimensions. It makes a difference between `reg [7:0] mr;` or `reg [0:7] mr;` when you select bit `mr[0]`.